# What does "The collected statistical data have been analysed and interpreted thoroughly" mean?

Tags: grammar, sequence-of-tenses

Does this sentence mean that some data was collected (in the certain point in the past), then has been analysed and interpreted (in the period of the time in the past)?

Should this sentence be written:

> The collected statistical data have been analysed and **have been** interpreted thoroughly.

Comment: Welcome to this site.  Could you possibly add to your statement an explanation of what it is about your quotation that you find problematic?  Is it that you think that analysis cannot be thorough?  Is it that you think that adverbs cannot be used to modified both of two verbs at the same time?"

Comment: Hello. The problematic for me is correct use of the grammar tenses. I don't know if the past tense is used well in this sentence.  Should I add 'have been' before the word 'interpreted'?

Comment: It's entirely a stylistic choice whether to explicitly repeat ***have been*** in the cited context (it's *assumed* to be "present" even if it's "deleted").

Comment: @FumbleFingers does the adverb 'thoroughly' also apply to the word 'analysed' or just to the 'interpreted' in this sentence?

Comment: The syntax is ambiguous on that point, but *logically* it's reasonable to assume the adverb ***thoroughly*** modifies *both* preceding verbs in this exact context. In the unlikely event the writer only wanted it to apply to "interpreted", he could have removed any ambiguity by writing *...have been analysed and **have been** interpreted thoroughly*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **signal a past time but not when in relation to the present time**:

The collected statistical data have been analyzed and interpreted thoroughly.

No need to repeat have been. It is past tense but vague about when.

If you want to signal something done in the past, unconnected to what is called the time of speaking, use simple past..

The collected statistical data **were analyzed and interpreted thoroughly**.

No need to repeat were. Here, it would be something like: last week, last month, last year.